# make for loop shorter by using another for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I am trying to make my for loop shorter see *before and after* but I get this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'U'` is it even possible to use it this way ?

*before*

```
<?php
for ($i=9; $i < 22; $i++) { 
//zet voor alle dagen van de week de gehuurde uuren in een array
$D1U[$i] = $resourceUsage['data']['usage']['110556']['2018'][5][$days[0]][$i][15];
$D2U[$i] = $resourceUsage['data']['usage']['110556']['2018'][5][$days[1]][$i][15];
$D3U[$i] = $resourceUsage['data']['usage']['110556']['2018'][5][$days[2]][$i][15];
$D4U[$i] = $resourceUsage['data']['usage']['110556']['2018'][5][$days[3]][$i][15];
$D5U[$i] = $resourceUsage['data']['usage']['110556']['2018'][5][$days[4]][$i][15];
$D6U[$i] = $resourceUsage['data']['usage']['110556']['2018'][5][$days[5]][$i][15];
$D7U[$i] = $resourceUsage['data']['usage']['110556']['2018'][5][$days[6]][$i][15];
}
?>
```

*after*

```
<?php
for ($d=1; $d < 8; $d++) { 
$D[$d]U[$i] = $resourceUsage['data']['usage']['110556']['2018'][5][$days[0]][$i][15];
}
?>
```

Comment: `$D[$d]U[$i]` is invalid syntax. Doing `$D1U`, `$D2U`, ... isn't the way to go here. Make it into an array instead.

Comment: You could accomplish it with a two-dimensional array, `$D[$d][$i]`
Rewrite it like following
```
for ($i=1; $i < 22; $i++) {
  for ($d=1; $d < 8; $8++) {
    $D[$d][$i] = $resourceUsage['data']['usage']['110556']['2018'][5][$days[0]][$i][15];

  }
}
```

Comment: I would not worry about making this for loop smaller as much I would worry about making a sensible way to store these variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use square brackets to address ["variable variables"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in PHP. You need to construct a string using concatenation and curly braces instead, e.g.

```
$d = 1; $i = 2;
${'D' . $d . 'U' . $i} = 'foo';
echo $D1U2; // foo
```

As a rule though, variables with numbers in them are generally a bad sign, as the syntax required to access them (as above) isn't exactly pretty. They're also inherently not very scalable. If you're able to refactor a little, I'd suggest using an array instead, e.g

```
$DU = [];

...

for ($d=1; $d < 8; $d++) { 
  $DU[$d][$i] = $resourceUsage['data']['usage']['110556']['2018'][5][$days[0]][$i][15];
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use variable variable.this is the link http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php. also refer to the caution to be addressed while using this method

```
for ($d=1; $d < 8; $d++) { 
${'D'.$d.'U'}[$i] = $resourceUsage['data']['usage']['110556']['2018'][5][$days[0]][$i][15];
}
```